# permutation - arranging of letters - vowels and consonants alternate

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The number of words that can be made by rearranging the letters of the word  ANANDITA so that vowels and consonants are alternate?

Comment: is answer 48....??

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Is [VCVCVCVC or CVCVCVCV] here necessary and sufficient to achieve 'alternatively'?

How many words can be made by rearranging NNDT? And how many by rearranging AAIA?

Comment: according to it..it will be..$\frac{4!}{2}$ and $\frac{4!}{3!}$

Comment: then answer will be 48..is it correct??

Comment: why its twice??..yes 96 is the answer given in book

Comment: ohkk..got it ..thanku

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 vowels and 4 consonats, hence there are only 2 (general) possibilities: vcvcvcvc or cvcvcvcv. Hence there are $2\cdot4\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot2=96$ possibilities. The numbers are: 2 general possibilities, 4 positions of I (there are 3 A), 2 N's out of 4, permutation of D and T.

Comment: $3$ times A and $1$ time I will not give you 4! possibilities.

Comment: @drhab Thank you! Correcting.

Comment: The product mentioned equals $96$ (which is correct).

Comment: @drhab Corrected. Thank you! It is time to go to sleep, if I do not see 3 A's or can not multiply correctly. :-(